# How to detect that a voltage source is not powered?

Tags: power, switches, ac, gpio

I need to detect when the switch SW1 is on and when it is off, and this input has to be sent to a GPIO of a microcontroller. I have no idea how to implement the circuit required to achieve this goal, so I would really appreciate somebody else's help.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhoh5f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is the voltage of V2?

Comment: The voltage is 110 V AC

Comment: It is not clear from your question WHY there is 110 VAC in the circuit? A better explanation of the context would be most helpful here. If you are trying to sense whether an existing mains-voltage circuit is energized or not, the safest way is to use an opto-coupler which will detect the mains voltage and output a safe, isolated logic level signal suitable for interfacing to a microcontroller. If you are implementing a switch circuit just for the microcontroller, then it is not at all clear why you are using 110VAC at all???

Comment: I need to "simulate" when the power is on and off from an AC source, and I need to use a switch like the ones you have on the walls. The resistor in the circuit just represents a load not really a resistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace SW1 with a two-pole switch. Use one pole to switch your circuit on and off, and connect the second pole to the GPIO and ground of your microcontroller. You may need to add a pull-up resistor to the GPIO pin if your microcontroller doesn't have one built-in.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMSsrw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change the existing circuit then here are a couple of 'add-in' circuits.

[image]

1. add a 110V ac relay (SPST)
2. build a capacitive supply to produce a low voltage dc (non isolated) supply and use an opto-coupler to isolate it.